# Vue.js/vuex ajax update components with ajax state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm using vue webpack template with vuex and I'm basically having issues with components not updating with the state.

I have a store

```
const state = {
  userData: {},
}
```

In my app I have a method

```
methods: {

    addUserData: function() {
        const that = this;
        axios.get('URL').then(function (response) { 

            let obj = response.data;
            that.$store.commit('addUserData', {obj});

        }); 
    },
```

which I call when it's mounted

```
mounted () {

    this.addUserData();

},
```

Which is updated with a mutation

```
const mutations = {
addUserData(state, {obj}) {
    state.userData = obj;
},}
```

Everything is fine up to here, the data is going into the store fine. But then I have a component which isn't working, as it's not waiting for the ajax to finish loading, nor is it binded in any way. I may well be doing this wrong here, but basically in my component I have

```
data () {
    return {
        weekData : {
            weekDataList: []....

methods: {

    tester: function(a) {

        // Sorting the userdata using lowdash
        this.weekData.weekDataList = _.values(this.$store.state.userData);

    },

},
```

I call this in the same manner as I did before

```
mounted () {

    this.tester();

},
```

The issue is that this.weekData.weekDataList always returns an empty array as the userData in the store hasn't managed to complete. I have dozens of methods performing various calculations, all based on this one array, so if one fails they all fail.

Perhaps my approach is wrong, but ideally I would like the data attributes to update once the store is updated? I tried doing this with computed properties and works fine with {{ whatever }}, but wasn't sure how to update the components data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were on the right paths. Computed properties is definitely the way to go here.
In you current situation your component knows nothing about the store in any reactive way. You just have a function that tries to read out the data at any given point and the correct data may be there or not.

So first of all, if the component is nested under the parent, as it seems to be `this.$store` will point to the same store. You should then try to use the needed value as a property, so it's reactive.

```
computed: {
  userData: function () {
     return this.$store.state.userData
  }
}
```

and while you are on it, also throw the weekdata into the computed properties:

```
computed: {
  userData: function () {
     return this.$store.state.userData
  },
  weekData: function () {
    return {
      weekDataList: _.values(this.userData)
    }
  }
}
```

By doing this, all the data will be reactive, and the `weekData` will update accordingly.

Hope this helps, and in general, when you are using Webpack already, I would consider starting to use the ES6 Syntax as it makes things more readable and some parts a little cleaner :)

Comment: Thanks @codebryo Yep that works great but I think userData is only accessible by using {{userData}} on the output. Can I use it somewhere, perhaps in another method or whatever, within the component like this.userData. I need to local data to update once the scope has updated with the ajax as other methods are in turn dependent on this one bit of data.

Comment: You can use `userData` just like any data property or method as Vue creates a getter and setter for it. Also, as it's computed they will autoupdate. `this.$store` is reactive, so as soon as that changes userData will be reevaluated and as that changes weekData will autoupdate again as well. So it's fine if everything happens async.

Comment: That makes sense and works in the other computed functions now. Say I wanted to get the first userData element, {{ userData[0] }} doesn't seem to work nor does returning the following on the userData computed property.

var arr = weekDataList: _.values(this.userData)
return arr[0]

Comment: Seems I'm wrong in that respect. I think I was completely thinking about the whole concept of Vue and computed methods incorrectly and using methods like traditional JS instead of computed properties. You've been a great help, thanks!

Comment: @webknit If this solved your problem, you should upvote the answer and accept it.

Comment: I already have, but apparently my votes don't show with me being a new member with less than 15 scores? Unless I'm doing something wrong?