# Vuejs: loading topojson from store and plot with d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, vue.js, vuex

The issue I am having is similar to this question:
[Vue.js/vuex ajax update components with ajax state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43204136/vue-js-vuex-ajax-update-components-with-ajax-state)

First, I want to load some static topojson file to the store. This happens on mount of the main vue instance in main.js:

```
new Vue({
    ...
    mounted () {
        this.$store.dispatch('topojsonStore/loadMunicipalityTopo', 
        'static/topojson_data/gem_2014.topojson')
    }
})
```

This gets loaded in the store without problems. In the component where I want to visualize this data, I can access this data from the store just fine:

```
computed: {
    getMunicipalityTopo () {
        return this.$store.getters['topojsonStore/getMunicipalityTopo']
    }
}
```

I put the drawing functionality under a method in the component:

```
methods: {
    plotMunicipalities () {
        var width = 650,
            height = 770
        var path = d3.geoPath()
        .projection(null) // TODO: fix projections
        var svg = d3.select('#map').append('svg')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height)
        // Load topojson from store
        let topoJsonData = this.getMunicipalityTopo
        svg.append('path')
        .attr('class', 'municipalities')
        .datum(topoJsonData)
        .attr('d', path)
      }
```

This works fine if I attach this to a click event in the template, like so:

```
<button @click="plotMunicipalities()">Plot municipalities</button>
```

I want, however, to draw this stuff automatically when the page is loaded, and not after a click event. This is where I run into the asynchronicity issues...
Putting this in the component, for example, does not work, as the data in the store is still not loaded:

```
mounted () {
    this.plotMunicipalities()
}
```

How should I go from here? How can I trigger the function when the data in the store is loaded? I should mention that later, different layers will be loaded. Some layers will be unchangeable by the user, but for this particular layer it will be possible for the user to change it. Should I use a different workflow for these different layers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Vamsi's method would definitely work, I ended up using a watcher in the component:

```
watch: {
// Execute draw functions when data in store is done loading
getMunicipalityTopo: function () {
  this.plotMunicipalities()
}
```

Works fine!

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is by setting up an global event bus by creating an empty vue instance

```
var EventBus = new Vue({});
```

Then make your `topojsonStore/loadMunicipalityTopo` action return a promise like this:

```
actions: {
    topojsonStore/loadMunicipalityTopo: ({commit}) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            commit(...);
            resolve();
        });
    }
}
```

Then dispatch the action so that you can make use of the success callback and emit an event like this:

```
new Vue({
    ...
    mounted () {
        this.$store.dispatch('topojsonStore/loadMunicipalityTopo', 
        'static/topojson_data/gem_2014.topojson').then(() => {
            EventBus.$emit('store-json-loaded');
        })
    }
})
```

Now in the created hook of the component where you want to draw setup an event listener like this:

```
created(){
    EventBus.$on('store-json-loaded', () => {
        this.plotMunicipalities();
    });
}
```